# Why do the buttons goes up?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I programmed a simple app with android studio and the layout that is shown in the app when I run it is different than the xml file I designed.

Here is a link of an image of the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBd7x.jpg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/subBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/subBtn"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addBtn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/divBtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:text="@string/addBtn"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/multBtn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/subBtn" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/n1EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/number1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.444"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/n2EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/number2"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/n1EditText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n1EditText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/multBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="108dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
    android:text="@string/multBtn"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/divBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
    android:text="@string/divBtn"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:layout_width="174dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:text="@string/resultView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.455"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n2EditText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.637" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think it might be related to the virtual device i'm using but I don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: change the layout width in the design view, check if tht makes a difference. As well could be a different android version on your vm.

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: Post the xml code . It is important to know which parent view you are using

Comment: I posted it now

Comment: @JohnJoe The other answers didn't clarify enough can you help?

Comment: @TheNiv check my anwser.

Comment: Imagine a `ConstraintLayout` as a collection of widgets hanging down from the top of the screen, each tied to the immediately top elements with the chains called "constraints". You don't need to tie the bottom widget to the ground unless it is required by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your `addBtn` and `subBtn` are not aware of the `n2EditText`. The `addBtn` depends on the `divBtn` and the `divBtn` is placed `336dp` above the bottom edge of the screen.

If you need the `addBtn` to appear below the `n2EditText` then you need to add a vertical constraint connecting to the `n2EditText`. Once your buttons are connected to their immediate top elements, you don't need to add the bottom constraint to the bottom edge of the screen.

Imagine a `ConstraintLayout` as a collection of widgets hanging down from the top of the screen, each tied to the immediately top elements with the chains called "constraints". You don't need to tie the bottom widget to the ground unless it is required by design.

Here is the modified layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
        android:id="@+id/subBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n2EditText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/n2EditText"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/subBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/subBtn"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/n1EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="n1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/n2EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="n2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/n1EditText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n1EditText"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/multBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divBtn"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/divBtn"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/divBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subBtn"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="res"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divBtn"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyway, when you have a lot of widgets, you may have to use a ScrollView to accommodate them all.

Comment: Thanks,now I understand.But I don't know how to use ScrollView. Im pretty new to android developing and I haven't used it yet. How does it accommodate them?

Comment: You can put the entire `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView`, that's all you need to do!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:text="submit"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n2EditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="add"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/subBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n2EditText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/n1EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="1"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.439"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/n2EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="2"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/n1EditText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n1EditText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="mult"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/subBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:text="div"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/subBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="resultView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.547"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divBtn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably on your layout editor and phone screen sizes are different. Use ConstraintLayout or some other add constraints to views

Comment: How can I check what is my phone screen size? I see that my layout editor screen size is 64dp

Comment: I think you should read this https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say definitly just looking at image but i think you are using facing problem because of your layout. Use LinearLayout to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" />

<!-- EditText: number1 -->
<!-- EditText Number2 -->

<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- 2 Buttons here -->

<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- 2 Buttons here -->

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general tips that can help:

- Check the constraints if you're using `ConstraintLayout` or relatives between view if you're using `RelativeLayout`;
- Check the values and the units of views;
- Check the screen resolution of your "Preview" pane and Emulator.

If it's possible to provide some additional information about the layout that is used, if these tips didn't help.

In preview pane you can find info about resolutions here:

[image]

In the emulator pane you can simple see the sizes in the column:

[image]